# MySQL - Enumerate all rows within a minute and keep the first one

Tags: mysql, row, enumerate, minute

I have a MySQL table with the following columns :

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date           | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time           | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gmt_offset     | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type           | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| yield_b        | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| yield_d        | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I am trying to keep one row per minute (the first one of every minute) using the following query:

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select t.*
    from (select t1.*,
                 (@rn := if(@prevd <> date or minute(time) <> @prevm, 1,
                            if(@prevd := date, if(@prevm := minute(time), 1, 1), 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from table1 t1 cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @prevd := 0, @prevm := 0) vars
          order by date, time
         ) t
     where seqnum = 1;


truncate table table1;

insert into table1(col1, . . ., coln)
    select col1, . . . , coln
    from temp_table1;
```

I try with this query to enumerate all rows within a minute, and then keep the first row for every minute.. But this doesn't work, it simply puts 1 in seqnum for every row, and does not get rid of any rows at all.

Can anybody help me make this query work and keep the first row of every minute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the columns `date` and `time` have `VARCHAR` types?

Comment: I imported these data from some CSV files, and then I had to change the format of date.. maybe what I am doing is not optimal but I think I couldn't import the data correctly if I didn't declare the columns as varchar...

Comment: Yes, you can. If they cannot be imported correctly then function `minute()` will fail in your query too. The [`LOAD DATA INFILE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) is pretty flexible, you can ignore columns, change their order and compute values from the imported values before storing them into the database.

Comment: No the function works I tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the logic was inverted in the first `if()`.  I think I was confused.  Apologies for that.

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select t.*
    from (select t1.*,
                 (@rn := if(@prevd = date and minute(time) = @prevm, @rn + 1,
                            if(@prevd := date, if(@prevm := minute(time), 1, 1), 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from table1 t1 cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @prevd := 0, @prevm := 0) vars
          order by date, time
         ) t
     where seqnum = 1;
```

The logic for the variable assignment in this case is:

- First clause does the comparisons and increments the `@rn` value.
- The next clauses assign the new values of the variables using nested `if()` calls, returning 1 for all possibilities.

The purpose of putting all the assignments in a single expression is not to create arbitrarily complicated SQL.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  If you have multiple expressions with variable assignments, then they may evaluated in the wrong order.

Comment: So basically you had to change  "  (rn := if(prevd <> date or minute(time) <> prevm, 1, " to "  (rn := if(prevd = date and minute(time) = prevm, rn + 1, " for the query to work ( I don't put the @ because it doesn't let me write many of these )  ? Thanks Gordon you are so fast in these MySQL queries !

Comment: @adrCoder . . . I don't know why I made that mistake the first time.  When I responsed to your comment on the first question, I looked over the previous answer and missed it.  This time it just screamed out

Comment: ok Gordon thanks, I just asked to make sure that the only change was indeed in this one line !